# Layout system for web

Tags: html, css, xaml, layout, javafx

I am Android and Java developer. I'm used to create apps with Linear or Stack alike layouts. So I'm interested if there's any layout system for web. I find HTML and CSS pretty complicated compared to other markup languages like XAML or JavaFX layouts. This question may sound silly to web developers but I would love to know if there's something similar to layouts for web.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

There are huge list of layout system in web development. You have to decide first which programming language layout are you concerned with?.

**In HTML and CSS, there are pre-processors, frameworks:**

Preprocessors are the software compiler look-a-like which converts their style of html coding into standard html, such processors are available for css too.

Jade, [HAML](http://haml.info/) are HTML pre-processors. [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/), [Bourbon](http://bourbon.io) are CSS Preprocessors.

If you are interested into full-stack framework for HTML, you will find [Twitter Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com), [Zurb's Foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com/) and [Bootswatch Paper](https://bootswatch.com/paper/) as popular options.

And if you are into web, only for web grid system: you will find hefty ammount of css grid system on github. While twitter bootstrap and zurb foundation comes pre-built and many other frameworks too.
[CSS Flex module](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) is another bigger alternative to many grid systems.